# How to make a directory in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how to create a directory path to save images for Windows, as I tried getExternalStorageDirectory(), but the image ends up not appearing,

```
static Future<String> saveImage(File file) async {

    Directory directory = Directory('C:/Users/user/Documents');
    
    if (!await directory.exists()) directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;

    String filename = 'image - ${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg';

    String savedPath = '${directory.path}/$filename';

    File(file.path);

    return savedPath;
  }
```

Comment: You should only ask one question at once on stackoverflow. But you could probably use the `filepicker` plugin to select a directory and then pass that in alongside the file.

Comment: Can you revert this to english? The stackoverflow guidelines require questions to be in english, otherwise they will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. This issue isn't that the directory doesn't exist, it's that you haven't written the file to it.

```dart
String filename = 'image - ${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg';
final copied = await file.copy('${directory.path}/$filename');
return copied.path;
```

Comment: I had already done it this way and it ended up not working either.